# deep copy hashtable

Tags: c#

How do I deep copy a hashtable to another new hashtable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public void CloneDict(Dictionary<K,V> dictionary) where V:IClonable 
{
     Dictionary<K,V> clonedOne = new Dictionary<K,V>();

     foreach(KeyValuePair<K,V> pair in dictoinary) {
         clonedOne(pair.Key, (V) pair.Value.Clone()
     }
}
```

Then implement the IClonable for whatever objects you are to store in the dictionary. Same approach can be applied to Hashtable but only as non-generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new one with the old as parameter:

```
Dictionary<a,b> dic=new Dictionary<a,b>(oldDict)
```

and the same for `HashSet<T>`. This constructs a new hashtable from the contents of the old one.

Note: If you're not using the default comparer you need to specify it again in the constructor.

> `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)` Initializes a new instance of the Dictionary class that contains elements copied from the specified IDictionary and uses the default equality comparer for the key type.

Comment: It doesn't deep copy, the keys/values that get stored in that new Dictionary is still the same objects as the ones in your old Dictionary.

Comment: @nos, not if they're value types.

Comment: I have both value types and reference types in the collection so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically works best..